# panda filtering on date range

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, filter

I have been researching this and have not been able to figure it out, so I need some guidance.

I am importing a csv and I'd like to filter it on multiple date. I convert the timestamp to a datetime and then parse out the date into its own column.

My dataframe

```
    open    high    low     close   volume  timestamp   datetime    date
5850    148.5700    148.83  148.535     148.6800    1054078     1629120600000   2021-08-16 13:30:00     2021-08-16
5851    148.7200    149.15  148.700     149.1400    536106  1629120660000   2021-08-16 13:31:00     2021-08-16
5852    149.1399    149.30  149.130     149.1700    420194  1629120720000   2021-08-16 13:32:00     2021-08-16
5853    149.1630    149.25  149.120     149.2200    344097  1629120780000   2021-08-16 13:33:00     2021-08-16
5854    149.2150    149.56  149.140     149.5600    629713  1629120840000   2021-08-16 13:34:00     2021-08-16
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
3895    162.6950    162.72  162.550     162.6300    300778  1659124500000   2022-07-29 19:55:00     2022-07-29
3896    162.6200    162.64  162.515     162.5499    260475  1659124560000   2022-07-29 19:56:00     2022-07-29
3897    162.5500    162.62  162.500     162.5699    314390  1659124620000   2022-07-29 19:57:00     2022-07-29
3898    162.5600    162.60  162.500     162.5250    471114  1659124680000   2022-07-29 19:58:00     2022-07-29
3899    162.5300    162.64  162.410     162.5700    1114601     1659124740000   2022-07-29 19:59:00     2022-07-29
```

and its info

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 96385 entries, 5850 to 3899
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------     --------------  -----         
 0   open       96385 non-null  float64       
 1   high       96385 non-null  float64       
 2   low        96385 non-null  float64       
 3   close      96385 non-null  float64       
 4   volume     96385 non-null  int64         
 5   timestamp  96385 non-null  int64         
 6   datetime   96385 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 7   date       96385 non-null  object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(4), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 6.6+ MB
```

I formulate the dates I want to filter

```
exp_fri = pd.date_range('2021-11-01','2022-07-31',freq='WOM-3FRI').strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
```

I have also tried the date range excluding the tolist fuction which is an dtype = datetime but given that the date column in my df is an object I believe I am doing a proper comparison.

```
exp_fri = pd.date_range('2021-11-01','2022-07-31',freq='WOM-3FRI').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
type(exp_fri)
```

I then try to filter using

```
df_expfri = df[df['date']].isin[exp_fri]
df_expfri
```

but get key error 'date'

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'date'

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [75], in <cell line: 3>()
          1 #https://datagy.io/filter-pandas/
          2 #east_west2 = df[df['Region'].isin(['West', 'East'])]
    ----> 3 df_expfri = df[df['date']].isin[exp_fri]
          4 df_expfri
    
    File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3505, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
       3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
       3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
    -> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
       3506 if is_integer(indexer):
       3507     indexer = [indexer]
    
    File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3623, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
       3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
       3622 except KeyError as err:
    -> 3623     raise KeyError(key) from err
       3624 except TypeError:
       3625     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
       3626     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
       3627     #  the TypeError.
       3628     self._check_indexing_error(key)
    
    KeyError: 'date'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are looking for `df[df['date'].isin(exp_fri)]` instead of `df[df['date']].isin[exp_fri]`. Should work on both variants of `exp_fri`; you could leave out the `.tolist()` here.

Comment: Ah, I see the brackets were a bit wrong and that did work...to an extent. I received an empty dataframe.

Comment: could it be the df column is 2021-11-19 and the date range string is '2021-11-19'?

Comment: What happens if you try `df[df.date.isin(['2021-08-16', '2022-07-29'])]` just as a test. Based on your df above, I'd expect a couple of rows to be returned. I.e. maybe there are just no expiration days in the set?

Comment: I get and error, the date column type is an object not datetime

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: Hmm. With that, I think you are probably not looking at the correct `df`. This error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'` means (in this case, anyway) that your df doesn't have a `date` column. Maybe you've overwritten the df somewhere? Try `print(df.columns)`. Is `date` in there. Or indeed, `df.info()`, `df.head()`

Comment: I wrote the dataframe to csv and opened in excel, the expiration friday 2022-07-15 is there, but as you suggested 'sorted_df[sorted_df.date.isin(['2022-07-15'])]' is not returning correctly

Comment: feel free to keep using df, my original import is df but then created a new one called sorted_df

Comment: Index(['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'timestamp', 'datetime',
       'date'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246975/discussion-between-j-billman-and-ouroboros1).